# Drag cursor in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, events, mouse-cursor

I need to set the drag cursor in some places, but I can't see it listed here http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp

In my case it appears when I drag some image :

[image: The drag cursor]
http://s2.subirimagenes.com/otros/previo/thump_8236773bgform29.jpg

Is there a code to use like body{cursor: drag} ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the move cursor paramater:

```
.target {cursor:move}
```

That cursor you are asking for is unique, if you want to use one with pure CSS then the best for this case is the move cursor.

**Edit:**
For a custom cursor like the one you see, you can use the URL property value

```
.target{ cursor: url(mycursor.gif), auto; }
```

You want to specify a default cursor at the end just incase the one specified by the URL cannot be used.

If you want this cursor only to appear when they are dragging then you'll have to apply this CSS rule to the element being dragged when the user clicks on it.

Comment: I need the hand ;) like in the picture.

Comment: Your picture is blocked by OpenDNS for me, maybe a different image hosting service would prevent it happening for others too?

Comment: Edited to explain using a custom cursor

Comment: I use Firefox 18 in ArchLinux with KDE the default cursor icon shows me a grabbing hand when i drag images. It must be some code to get this cursor and i'm sure is be present in every cursor theme

Answer (score 3):

You may be able to use the vendor-specific grab cursor, but I don't think the support is quite there yet.  It might be best to use a custom icon or, as suggested by Chris B., the move cursor.

```
.grab {
   cursor: url("http://www.example.com/openhand.cur") 8 8, move;
   cursor: -moz-grab;
   cursor: -webkit-grab;
}

.grabbing {
   cursor: url("http://www.example.com/closedhand.cur") 8 8, move;
   cursor: -moz-grabbing;
   cursor: -webkit-grabbing;
}
```

Comment: @user, The image depicts a blue cursor that resembles a 3D pie-chart. The only way to get that type of cursor is using a custom image.

Comment: The cursor is a standard cursor present in my cursor theme. You should have one similar in your O.S

Comment: I do not have any cursors that look like that in any of the default themes provided on a standard installation of Windows 7 Professional.

Comment: Have you try to drag the stackoveflow logo. It should appear, offcourse it not will be blue like me, im using KDE 4.9. But should see a grabbing hand similar.

Comment: When I drag the StackOverflow logo, I am shown the "no-drop" cursor.  In the Windows mouse properties, this is labeled as "Unavailable".