# Set CSS cursor while dragging

Tags: javascript, css, drag-and-drop, draggable

I would like to set the [cursor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor) while dragging an element. Grab and grabbing cursor work, but the moment an element is being dragged the cursor changes to the default:

[image]

What’s the recommended way of handling this? Looks like this requires a Javascript solution because there’s no actual CSS selector available for a “dragging” element.

Related questions, e.g. [Changing cursor while dragging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16259638/changing-cursor-while-dragging), [Drag cursor in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14319850/drag-cursor-in-javascript), or [CSS for grabbing cursors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5697067/css-for-grabbing-cursors-drag-drop) don’t seem to work and are a bit dated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the cursor icon when dragging in HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30052111/how-to-change-the-cursor-icon-when-dragging-in-html5)